# Gnome 3.10 on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, 13.04, gnome

Is it possible to install the newly released gnome version (3.10) on 13.04? If it's possible, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install Gnome 3.10 on Ubuntu 13.04, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

I went a ahead and installed Gnome 3.10, just to see if there is any issues with it.  I have installed it on 13.04, and had no problems.  See images bellow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sup>Source:[LinuxG](http://linuxg.net/)</sup>

Comment: And this will work when I'm on gnome 3.8 now? It'll not mess things up ?

Comment: I don't see why it won't work, plus you can always uninstall if you don't like it.  I personally doesn't like or use Gnome.

Comment: That method installed version 3.9.92 and changed from GDM to LightDM, some way to change to GDM again ? Like it better..

Comment: Install using Software Center or from terminal `sudo apt-get install gdm`

Comment: That made my PC useless.. No login screen.. LightDM get me in, but I'm missing some parts of menus etc.. On turn off pop-up there's no buttons.. Thats an example..

Comment: Do this, `sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm`, and choose GDM from the menu.  Make sure to restart your computer.  If you want your LightDM back, type `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`.

Comment: Did that, well I'm back in Unity now.. Not stable neither.. Think I install 13.10 :P To much crashing now..Applicationcenter wont open, crashes everytime. Compiz crashes.. Unitybar won't show (I have auto-hide).. As you see, too much :P hehe

Comment: I'm going to install it just to see, and I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok! Im on gnome again now 3.9.92 as above. With LightDM, don't want to try to install GDM again ;) The buttons works now, they shows. I did 'sudo apt-get dist-upgrade'..

Comment: It works OK, see additions in the answer.

Comment: Hm, ok.. It's 3.10 and not 3.9 ? I'll try gdm later! Thanks!

Comment: Okay... I've got 3.10 and its interesting... once GDM is working it works, but with flaws. Currently I'm updating through Terminal because software update is crashing, I get those nice system problem messages every time I click out of the last one, and sometimes searching freezes. I'd just wait for 13.10... it seems it isn't fully stable on 13.04 :) *Edit* No Gnome Apps seem to be working :)

Comment: The issues are not with GDM but ubuntu not letting GDM run properly I think! x-(