# How to Upgrade Gnome 3.4 to 3.10?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, upgrade, ppa

I have been happily using the Gnome desktop environment to complete my day-to-day computing. Recently, I learned that Gnome 3.10 was released. I tried to update using the ppa: `gnome3-team/gnome3`. However, `apt-get update` is unable to find that ppa. I also discovered that I am actually using Gnome 3.4.1, not 3.8.x. How can I upgrade?\

Notes: I installed using `sudo apt-get install gnome` and am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/350543/gnome-3-10-on-ubuntu-13-04/350631#350631).

Comment: I have mentioned here http://askubuntu.com/questions/22946/how-do-i-install-and-use-the-latest-version-of-gnome/393254#393254

Comment: That will install gnome 3.4 but not 3.8 or later.

Comment: gnome 3.8 or later versions are not available for ubuntu 12.04.See here https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gnome-shell/

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal, run

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```